# Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-windowmanager

Below is my utility method for showing alert dialog in my application

```
private void displayInternetAlert(final Context context) {
        if (!((GlobalActivity) context).isFinishing() && context instanceof GlobalActivity) {
            ((GlobalActivity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (Validator.isNull(internetDialog)) {
                        internetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Util.createCustomAlertDialog(context)).create();
                        internetDialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.internet_disable));
                        internetDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, context.getString(R.string.settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                /*
                Don't need to write onactivity result now as we try to connect every time
                 */
                                context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        internetDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, context.getString(R.string.ignore), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        internetDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                internetDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.dialog_cancel_button));
                                internetDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                                internetDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.dialog_cancel_button));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if (!internetDialog.isShowing()) {
                        internetDialog.show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

and Below is my GlobalActivity class

```
public class GlobalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Nullable
    @Bind(R.id.adView)
    public AdView adView;

    public GlobalActivity() {
        ExceptionHandler.getExceptionHandler().setActivity(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ad_system);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        loadGoogleAdd();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(Validator.isNotNull(adView)){
            adView.resume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(Validator.isNotNull(adView)){
            adView.pause();
        }
        Util.setSharedPreferences(this, Util.SHARED_PREFERENCE_PREFERENCES, Util.EXPOSE_GSON.toJson(Util.getPreferences(this)));

    }

    private void loadGoogleAdd() {
        if (adView != null) {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().
                    addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }

    public void loadErrorActivity() {
        startActivity(new Intent(GlobalActivity.this, ErrorActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(Validator.isNotNull(adView)){
            adView.destroy();
        }
        Request.getRequest().dismissProgressDialog(this);
    }
}
```

from which I am extending all activities and in that activity I am replacing fragments although I made check for activity finishing.

But I'm still receiving this exception in SM-G935F (Samesung Galaxy s7 edge). I'm using appcompat 23.1.1. is it platform or device specific issue or whether I'm making any mistake please help me in finding solution for this.

Any help is appreiciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it possible to display dialog from background thread, with assumption method `displayInternetAlert` is called inside activity/fragment, you can display dialog directly like this:

```
private void displayInternetAlert(final Context context) {
    if (!((GlobalActivity) context).isFinishing() && context instanceof GlobalActivity) {
            if (Validator.isNull(internetDialog)) {
                internetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Util.createCustomAlertDialog(context)).create();
                internetDialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.internet_disable));
                internetDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, context.getString(R.string.settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        /*
        Don't need to write onactivity result now as we try to connect every time
         */
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                internetDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, context.getString(R.string.ignore), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                internetDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        internetDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.dialog_cancel_button));
                        internetDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        internetDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.dialog_cancel_button));
                    }
                });
            }
            if (!internetDialog.isShowing()) {
                internetDialog.show();
            }
        }
}
```